# Normalization of Integral Affine Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $k$ is a field and set $A=k[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^3\rangle$. Let $\varphi:A\longrightarrow k[t]$ be given by $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$, and let   $$\left(f,f^\sharp\right):\operatorname{Spec} k[t]\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$$ be the corresponding morphism of schemes. I want to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I have shown that $\varphi$ is injective (yet not surjective) and found that the integral closure of $A$ is $k[t]$. In particular, we see that $\varphi$ is integral. It follows from going-up that $f$ is surjective. Moreover, by considering the monomorphism $A/\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)\longrightarrow k[t]/\mathfrak p$ (where $\mathfrak p$ is an ideal), we too get that $f$ is a closed map.

It remains to show that $f$ is injective (since closed, continuous bijections are homeomorphisms), but I can't seem to figure out why this is the case.

Since $\varphi$ is not surjective, I cannot set $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)=\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$ and apply $\varphi$ to realize $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak q$.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious; I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show every point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ only has one preimage. This is clear for the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, since the non-generic points of $\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ are closed.

If $\mathfrak{q} \in \operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ maps to $(x, y)$, then $\varphi(x) = t^2 \in \mathfrak{q}$. Hence, $t \in \mathfrak{q}$, so $(t)$ is the only point of $\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ mapping to $(x,y) \in \operatorname{Spec} A$.

Now we can deal with the other points all at once. For this note that the induced field extension $K(A) \hookrightarrow k(t)$ is surjective since $t$ is mapped to by $y/x$, so we can identify $K(A)$ with $k(t)$.

By the Jacobian criterion $(x,y) \in \operatorname{Spec} A$ is the only singular point, so if $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} A$ is any other non-generic prime ideal, $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a DVR.

If $\mathfrak{q} \in \operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ maps to $\mathfrak{p}$, then  $k[t]_{\mathfrak{q}}$ dominates $ A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as local subrings in $k(t) = K(A)$. Since valuation rings are maximal with this property (cf. Atiyah-Macdonald exercise 5.27), the map $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \hookrightarrow k[t]_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is an isomorphism.

Hence, the only way $\mathfrak{q}$ and $\mathfrak{q}'$could map to $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} A$ is if $k[t]_{\mathfrak{q}}$ and $k[t]_{\mathfrak{q'}}$ agree as subrings of $k(t)$, which can then only happen if $\mathfrak{q} = \mathfrak{q}'$.